# Reformatting an array

Tags: php, cakephp

In short, I need a way to change:

```
Array
(
    [CrmOrder] => Array
        (
            [crm_schedule_id] => 59
        )

)
```

...into this (using PHP)....

```
Array
(
    [CrmOrder] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [crm_schedule_id] => 59
                )
        )
)
```

The reason I need to do this is because I want to use the CakePHP [saveAll()](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1031/Saving-Your-Data) function with an array that I'm getting from the [Wizard Component](https://github.com/jaredhoyt/cakephp-wizard/wiki/Step-3%3a-Data-Retrieval-and-Wizard-Completion). Cake's saveAll needs the data to be one level deeper because CrmOrder belongsTo CrmPerson which hasMany CrmOrder.

As this isn't necessarily a Cake specific question, I'm also adding the 'php' tag to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to leverage the FormHelper to produce the intended output like so:

```
echo $this->Form->input('CrmOrder.0.crm_schedule_id');
```

(Note the `0` in dot-notation. See second code block on [this page in the manual](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1032/Saving-Related-Model-Data-hasOne-hasMany-belongsTo).)

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right deizel. I've actually done this before but the whole wizard component way of doing things just threw me and made me forget. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
$input  = array( /* your data */ );
$output = $input;
$output['CrmOrder'] = array($output['CrmOrder']);
```

Comment: +1 for simplicity. Same as doing `$output = array('CrmOrder' => array($output['CrmOrder']));`

Answer (score 1):

```
$newArray = array();
foreach( $oldArray as $key => $value ) {
    $newArray[ $key ] = array( $value );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/0pyfQV):

```
$data = array(
  'CrmOrder' => array(
    'crm_schedule_id' => 59,
  ),
);

$data = array_map(function($v){return array($v);}, $data);

var_dump($data);
```